# Cannot see messages on mosquitto_sub terminal

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

I have wrote the sample code to test mqtt with mosquitto but its not working. I cannot see the messages being published on the subscribed window.

Below is my code

```
const client = broker.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');

client.on('connect', function() {
  client.subscribe(config.topic, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      client.publish('test/topic', 'Hello Test');
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});

client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
  console.log(message.toString());
  client.end();
});
```

on cmd terminal

```
mosquitto_sub -v -t 'test/topic' -h test.mosquitto.org
```

But I cannot see the message

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted, but the topic you are using is also being used by others on test.mosquitto.org. I suggest you download a copy of mosquitto and run your tests locally.

Comment: @hardillb I have already downloaded it, how can I run my tests locally, is it something like on localhost? can you please post any example?

Comment: @hardillb it worked locally :), but what about with mqtt://test.mosquitto.org?

Comment: The colde works fine for me on `test.mosquitto.org` (with a different test topic). Also worth noting that `test.mosquitto.org` is purely for testing (normally that new client libraries work with mosquitto) you shouldn't be using it for anything else and you should pick very random topics to prevent clashing with anybody else